# Is there a better option than reinterpret_cast<char*> when reading from std::istream?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, readfile, istream

I have the following piece of code:

```
std::istream is;
// ... stream initialization ... 
while(is)
{
  uint32_t next4Bytes = 0;
  is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&next4Bytes), 4);
  if(next4Bytes == 218893066)
  {
    is.seekg(-4, std::ios_base::cur);
    break;
  }
  else
    is.seekg(-3, std::ios_base::cur);
}
```

Is there any other better way than `reinterpret_cast<char*>` to read 4 bytes from `std::istream` into a `uint32_t`? (obviously other than c-style cast)

Comment: You can do `union fourBytes{uint32_t integer; char chars[4];}` (I know it's undefined behavior). Not sure if it's "better" but it's different, so there's that.

Comment: `char *readBuf ;
uint32_t next4Bytes ;
 is.read(readBuf , 4);
memcpy(&next4Bytes , readBuf, 4);` this with out any typecasting

Comment: In my personal opinion: Think about writing your own `toCharPtr` (or similar) wrapper function. Casting to `char*` is very common, legal,  **and necessary** in IO related code, so that I don't see a reason to get my code cluttered with those reinterpret casts (which I treat as a big exclamation mark under most other circumstances)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is, and I don't think you need one.  You're taking four bytes and re-interpreting them; `reinterpret_cast` precisely describes your intent.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to wrap that cast in a templated reader function though:

```
template<typename T>
std::streamsize read(T* out, std::istream& stream, size_t count=1) {
    stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(out), sizeof(T)*count);
    return stream.gcount();
}
```

If you don't care about reading arrays, you may even omit the count argument and have it even simpler. There are some ways to modify this to your own needs. Instead of returning just gcount, you could divide it by sizeof(T) if you're interested in how many values were actually read, instead of how many bytes were read. (This is very similar to the way fread's return value works). Or you could throw an exception if not all data could be read.

Comment: For c++11 compliant compilers, I like adding `static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value,"Cannot be used on non-trivially copyable types)`.  That way the compiler can reject an attempt to use this function on more complicated types, such as `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use C-style cast, actually the same but shorter to write

```
is.read((char*)&next4Bytes, 4);
```

Comment: I'd upvote, but the OP explicitly excluded c-style casts.

Comment: Ups, didn't see it. My fault

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that `read` reads bytes, as opposed to `>>` operator, which is a high level construct.

You read bytes either to `char` or `unsigned char`, because this is what bytes are all about. Trying to go around this pretty much cancels the purpose of `read` which is to read bytes.

So if what's bothering you is the verbosity of `reinterpret_cast` , use templates.

If what's bothering you is the fact that you have to read bytes into an integer, try to store the integer as string in the first place and extract it with proper `>>` operator.